# SQL join statement (counting)

Tags: sql, join

So I've tried to solve this for about 1 hour with no success...

I'm trying to combine two tables with one SQL statement. I have one table with all of the player info named "skaters" and another table called "descriptions" which contains multiple descriptions connected to the skaters by an ID.

So the thing I want to do is count how many descriptions that have been added in my description table about a specific skater. What is the SQL-statement for that?

EDIT: Now I know what was wrong... I wrote "description" instead of "descriptions". One hour wasted because of that. What a joke.

Comment: What query have you tried so far ?

Comment: Without knowing what you have tried, the only answer is to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between `skaters` and `descriptions` is one to many.  This query isn't too terrible, though:

```
SELECT count(d.id) FROM descriptions d
LEFT JOIN skaters s ON s.id = d.skater_id
WHERE s.name = 'Some Name';
```

Comment: That would return back a row of description counts *per skater*. It also needs to be filtered via a WHERE clause to a single skater.

Comment: Just added that in.  Phone calls + SQL don't mix well, heh

Answer (score 0):

You just need join the two tables and then do COUNT(*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM skaters s
   , descriptions d
WHERE s.id = d.skater_id
  AND s.name = 'Somebody'
```

Replace the `AND s.name = 'Somebody'` line with however you're going to filter the one skater (could be id, could be name, etc).